# Replace <table> tag with dom in php

Tags: php, dom, removechild

I would like to trace al  tag and replace it with [table]. May i know how can i do it via html parser in php?

For example:

```
hello there

<table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>

some text

<table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>

some text

<table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>
```

to:

```
hello there

[table]

some text

[table]

some text

[table]
```

may I know how can i do it with removechild to replace the table tag and replacechild?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**view.html**

```
hello there
<table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>
some text
<table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>
some text
<table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>
```

**parse.php**

```
<?php
// Example: Load your view (html) into a string
$html = file_get_contents("view.html");

while(strpos($html, "<table>") !== false) {
    $start = strstr($html, '<table>', true);
    $end   = substr(strstr($html, '</table>'), 8);
    $html  = $start ."[table]" . $end;
}

echo $html;
```

**output**

```
hello there
[table]
some text
[table]
some text
[table]
```

Comment: I only want to do it in dom and not regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You do so by replacing all those `<table>` elements with a new textnode:

```
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');

while ($table = $tables->item(0)) {
    $table->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $table->ownerDocument->createTextNode('[table]'),
        $table
    );
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

The important part is here that while you remove the tables from the document, the order changes, too. Therefore I have used a `while` loop and the condition is to continue as long as there are still tables.

If there aren't any more tables, `$tables->item(0)` will return `NULL` which equals `FALSE`. The loop will be exited.

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>

    hello there

    [table]

    some text

    [table]

    some text

    [table]</div></body></html>
```

This is the full example ([Demo](https://eval.in/165745)):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320608/replace-table-tag-with-dom-in-php
 * @link https://eval.in/165745
 */

$html = <<<HTML
<div>

    hello there

    <table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>

    some text

    <table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>

    some text

    <table><tr><td>Some text</td></tr></table>

</div>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

/** @var DOMNodeList|DOMElement[] $tables */
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');

while ($table = $tables->item(0)) {
    $table->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $table->ownerDocument->createTextNode('[table]'),
        $table
    );
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```